# "Он был слишком гордым, чтобы подслушивать" - здесь придаточное изъяснительное?

Tags: синтаксис

> Он был слишком гордым, **чтобы подслушивать телефонный разговор жены.**

Неужели это предложение изъяснительное?

Answer (score 3):

> *Он был слишком гордым, **чтобы подслушивать телефонный разговор жены**.*
>
> Неужели это предложение изъяснительное?

Нет, не изъяснительное. **Придаточное меры и степени** (в какой мере он был горд?).

Вот как похожее предложение разбиралось в книге  [***[Иванова В.А., Потиха З.А., Розенталь Д.Э. "Занимательно о русском языке", М., 1990]:***](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Tt38AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=%22%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%20%D0%AF%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22&source=bl&ots=X90gQr0j4T&sig=XG7bmXa-yuhDSg-nsche_dfTtik&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDk6fSs7TVAhWNhRoKHUPSAMIQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%3A%20%D0%AF%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%22&f=false)

> Как разбирать предложение: ***Я слишком был счастлив, чтобы хранить в
>   сердце чувство неприязненности*** (Пушкин)? — Придаточное предложение
>   имеет здесь в качестве соотносительного слова в главном предложении
>   наречие меры *слишком* (образуется сочетание *слишком  —  чтобы*,
>   указывающее на предельную меру или степень признака, действия,
>   состояния). **Такие предложения рассматриваются как разновидность
>   придаточных меры и степени** (в какой мере я был счастлив?).

Answer (score 1):

Это СПП является **частным вариантом предложений с местоименно-союзной связью.**

Вот возможные варианты подобных предложений: Он **такой** гордый, **что** не станет подслушивать. Он **не так** воспитан, **чтобы** подслушивать. Здесь указательные слова обозначают степень признака, а придаточные имеют значения следствия (союз ЧТО) или ирреального следствия (союз ЧТОБЫ).

**Он был слишком гордым, чтобы подслушивать телефонный разговор жены.** Это предложение отличается тем, что   степень признака здесь выражена не местоименным словом, а наречием.  Здесь два значения: степень признака и ирреальное следствие. Изъяснительного значения здесь нет.

В школьной практике считается, что  такие предложения имеют **два значения**:степень признака  и следствие, цель, сравнение.

Например: Книга **такая** интересная, **что** невозможно оторваться (следствие). Мы иногда говорим **так, будто** нас зовут во власть, а мы делаем выбор: идти или не идти (сравнение). Поступайте **так, чтобы** потом не жалеть (цель).

Comment: Является ли полным список типов придаточных (см. ссылку)?  Если да, то какому типу из этого списка соответствует обсуждаемое предложение? http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/4219-temy_razdela_2__slozhnoe_predlozhenie_.html

Comment: Да, это придаточное образа действия и степени. 2.2.5, но частный вариант.

Comment: Что-то у меня в голове не укладывается. "Достаточно горд, чтобы сделать что-то" - понятно по смыслу и грамматически (степень достаточности):  "достаточно, чтобы". Но "слишком горд, чтобы сделать что-то" - смысл другой (отрицательный) и грамматически не согласуется: "слишком, чтобы" (?!).

Comment: Но смысл-то понятен:он слишком гордый, поэтому не будет подслушивать, то есть это следствие.. Мысль одна, а различных форм для ее выражения много. Мне кажется, что вы напрасно считаете союз ЧТОБЫ преимущественно целевым, например: Я хочу, чтобы ты приехал (здесь желание в изъяснительном предложении), то есть в общем союз ЧТОБЫ выражает ирреальную модальность.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, здесь придаточное цели. Для большей ясности вернем "выпавшие" слова:

Он был слишком гордым **для того**, чтобы подслушивать телефонный разговор жены.

Comment: тоже так думала, но потом потерялась в вопросах: "гордым для чего?" или "гордым для какой цели?"

Comment: По-моему, вы не так понимаете. Здесь, кажется, сказуемое "был слишком гордым". От всего сказуемого ставим вопрос "для чего?". Иначе - бессмыслица. Но я не лингвист, могу ошибаться

Comment: М_Г: cогласна с Вами! I was just lazy to put down the whole predicate =)